# How to combine 2 select statement in if exist?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT 1
FROM [job] WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE MemberCode = 'pay'
    AND CampaignID = '2'
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM [product] WITH (NOLOCK)
        WHERE MemberCode = 'pay'
            AND CampaignID = '2'
        )
```

Based on this query I want to get the records in both queries. I tried this and its not working.

For example if the first select statement returns no record but the second select statement has records, I still want it to show. I tried using `union` and it works just wondering if using an exist will work or not?

Comment: If you use `exists` and one record does not exist it won't show. That is how it should work.

Comment: @juergend is there other way to combine both statement without union or join

Comment: Why don't you want to use union or join? Its really not clear what you are trying to achieve... maybe add sample data and expected results.

Comment: Union and exists are quite different things... if union returns the desired results, its probably the tool for the job.

Comment: Read Aaron Bertrand's [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `outer join`:

```
select select(1) from FROM [job] WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE MemberCode = 'pay'
    AND CampaignID = '2'

    outer  join

      select(1)
        FROM [product] WITH (NOLOCK)
        WHERE MemberCode = 'pay'
            AND CampaignID = '2'
```